# Unable to create AVD in Eclipse - clicking OK does nothing

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to create my first AVD in Eclipse and I follow the directions I've seen online, but when I click OK nothing happens.  OK is enabled, but clicking does nothing.  Any ideas?  I added another example.

[image: AVD]

[image: AVD2]

Comment: try to restart adb and create again..

Answer (score 0):

Use Eclipse SR1 (eclipse-standard-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64). SR2 not work properly with ADT plugin.

Answer (score 0):

to create an AVD by opening "AVD manager.exe" from "Android SDK" for creating new AVD try to open directly AVD Manager.exe in SDK folder.